# To highlight the radio button on expanding the panel in expansion panel

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I have placed radio button inside each `expansion-panel` of `accordion` like this:

[image]

I want to highlight the **ratio button** on clicking particular **expansion-panel** and if i close the panel highlighting should go :

[image]

**NOTE:** I want to highlight the radio-button **only on clicking the panel not on clicking the  radio-button**.

[Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhuunt?file=app/expansion-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the pretty easier way to change the checkbox as panel status.

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel #panel1>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header >
      <mat-panel-title>

         <mat-radio-button [checked]="panel1.expanded">Panel 1</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
              Panel 1 comes here
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel  #panel2>>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
         <mat-radio-button [checked]="panel2.expanded"> Panel 2</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                  Panel 2 comes here
  </mat-expansion-panel>
   <mat-expansion-panel  #panel3>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
                <mat-radio-button [checked]="panel3.expanded">Panel 3</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                  Panel 3 comes here
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhuunt-flryaz

Comment: Once again thanks for answer..:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this ? I only added to the first one ...

```
    <mat-expansion-panel>
     <mat-expansion-panel-header >
       <mat-panel-title (click)="ww.checked=!ww.checked" >
        <mat-radio-button checked="false" #ww>Panel 1</mat-radio-button>
       </mat-panel-title>
       </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          Panel 1 comes here
       </mat-expansion-panel>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhuunt-2r2pf3

Comment: But it is checking only for one panel, i want for each panel.

Comment: If click particular panel, only that panels `radio-button` as to be `highlighted` not other panel's.

Comment: check it  now, I updated the demo  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhuunt-2r2pf3

Comment: Please read my question once..:)

Comment: here you go!  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhuunt-2r2pf3

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: No problem, happy to see that helps! :)